# The difference between "krümmen" and "beugen"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Both mean "to bend" but are there any differences in usage of these words?

Comment: I believe that your question would benefit from a little more detail: Where and what did you look up? Did you find anything at all that hints to differences in usage? - Basically: Do you have proof, that this cannot (easily) be looked up in a dictionary? :)

Answer (score 2):

By way of adding some thoughts to other answers here: I am not sure if the difference between *biegen* and *krümmen* can really fully be explained semantically, i.e. by contrastive definitions of meaning. I rather think it is more a question of pragmatics: how words are used by tradition.

As Janka correctly points out you would say

> Der Weg krümmte sich.

rather than

> *Der Weg bog sich.

If you want to apply the semantical concepts "use *biegen* when it is on purpose, use *krümmen* when it is a deformation" you run into problems here. Is it necessarily a deformation that the street bends or makes a turn? Or is it on purpose?

I am afraid, the only safe way for using *krümmen* and *biegen* correctly is knowing (from passive and active use) what word is usually used in combination with what other words.

> der Auspuffkrümmer

not: *der Auspuffbogen* - although this part of an automobile is on purpose formed so (exhaust manifold)

> Die Banane ist krumm

not: *die Banane ist gebogen*, although that's how God created it (or whoever)

> Das Rohr ist gebogen (on purpose)
>
> Das Rohr ist gekrümmt (on purpose)
>
> Das Rohr ist krumm (deformation; not as it should be)

Although there are some examples where one can argue that the rule "*krumm* = deformation, *gebogen* = on purpose) applies, e.g.

> Steh nicht so krumm!

Somebody gets reprimanded for his unstraight posture.

> Nimm's mir nicht krumm!

*Don't be mad at me for this.*

> Das kriegen wir schon wieder hingebogen.

*We will fix it*, especially metaphorically (without anything being bent physically).

there is no way for a learner of German to derive the correct expression from a rule. You still have to know from experience what's the usual thing to say.

Answer (score 1):

**Krumm** is an adjective meaning *bent out of shape*. The verb **sich krümmen** means to bend yourself out of shape.

> Der Weg krümmte sich.
>
> Sie krümmte sich vor Lachen.

Very seldomly, it's not used reflexive:

> Die Gravitation krümmt die Raumzeit.

Most other times, *biegen* or *verbiegen* ist used.

> Die Gravitation verbiegt die Raumzeit.

**Biegen** and **verbiegen** means applying force so something becomes *gebogen* (intended shape), *verbogen* (bent out of shape) or simply *krumm*.

> An deinem Auto ist ja alles verbogen.

Sometimes, the intended shape is somewhat metaphorical:

> Er biegt sich die Wahrheit zurecht.

---

The verb **beugen** means flexing joints.

> Sie beugt die Knie.
>
> Er beugt sich nach unten.

Comment: In the sentence "Er biegt sich die Wahrheit zurecht."  why is zurechtbiegen reflexive in this case?

Comment: Because he's betraying himself. Non-reflexive is also possible, but the reflexive one happens to be a common phrase.

Comment: In my experience, especially in combination with *Raumzeit* you would always use *krümmen*, never *verbiegen*. At least that's my summary after reading a dozen books on that topic over the years.

Comment: Yes, that's why I included this as one of the rare examples in which someone/something *krümmt* another thing. It's the preferred phrase.

Comment: During years of work in astrophysics and some teaching of General Relativity I never heard „verbiegt die Raumzeit“. I don’t consider this idiomatic, at least in professional texts.